# How to add a shadow / border / elevation to an icon in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to add a shadow to my icon in Jetpack compose, so that the image & text have a (roughly) similar shadow.

[image: Dummy-Image from https://www.123rf.com/photo_111707392_big-data-vector-icon-isolated-on-transparent-background-big-data-transparency-logo-concept.html]
[image]

```
Text(
    text = "HAS SHADOW",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(
        shadow =  Shadow(
            color = Color(0x4c000000),
            offset = Offset(2f, 2f),
            blurRadius = 7f
        )
    ),
)

Text(
    text = "HAS NO SHADOW",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
)
```

Please note: As you can see above, the icon is partly transparent and i want to keep it that way -> solutions like "Wrap it in a FloatingActionButton" won't work

Can i do this in compose or do i have to ask my designer to add a shadow?

Answer (score 11):

For **shadow** and **elevation**

```
Modifier.shadow(elevation: Dp, shape: Shape, clip: Boolean)
```

For **border**

```
Modifier.border(border: BorderStroke, shape: Shape)
```

Also, check the [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers-list) for **other border** function variants.

Comment: Both of these functions require a shape, which i can't provide, since my icon is not trivial. Or did i misunderstand you?

Comment: This answer doesn't really explain anything....

Comment: Where are you setting the value of the Shadow?