# Jetpack Compose icon shadow/elevation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to have an Icon (with ImageVector) component with a shadow/elevation in Jetpack Compose?

I want to make an IconButton with an elevated Icon but there seems to be no solution available for this problem. Things like `Modifier.shadow()` will only draw a shadow box around my icon and the Icon component itself has no elevation parameter.

This question seems like a duplicate of [How to add a shadow / border / elevation to an icon in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592070/how-to-add-a-shadow-border-elevation-to-an-icon-in-jetpack-compose) at first glance, but that question is not referring to the Icon component in combination with an ImageVector. Also, the proposed solution does not work and it wasn't updated in 6 months.

To further clarify, I want my Icon to look like this:

[image: icon with shadow]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you require is a library that converts imageVectors or xml files into `Path`. As i know of there is no built-in library for this. There are probably few out there that converts into Path or Shape.

When you have a shape or path what you need to do is draw with this shape as Modifier or into Canvas

```
fun Modifier.vectorShadow(
    path: Path,
    x: Dp,
    y: Dp,
    radius: Dp
) = composed(
    inspectorInfo = {
        name = "vectorShadow"
        value = path
        value = x
        value = y
        value = radius
    },
    factory = {

        val paint = remember {
            Paint()
        }

        val frameworkPaint = remember {
            paint.asFrameworkPaint()
        }

        val color = Color.DarkGray
        val dx: Float
        val dy: Float
        val radiusInPx: Float

        with(LocalDensity.current) {
            dx = x.toPx()
            dy = y.toPx()
            radiusInPx = radius.toPx()
        }


        drawBehind {

            this.drawIntoCanvas {

                val transparent = color
                    .copy(alpha = 0f)
                    .toArgb()

                frameworkPaint.color = transparent

                frameworkPaint.setShadowLayer(
                    radiusInPx,
                    dx,
                    dy,
                    color
                        .copy(alpha = .7f)
                        .toArgb()
                )

                it.drawPath(path, paint)


            }
        }
    }
)
```

Usage

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(8.dp)
) {

    val center = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        150.dp.toPx()
    }
    val path1 = createPolygonPath(center, center, 6, center)
    val path2 = createPolygonPath(center, center, 5, center)

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(300.dp)
            .vectorShadow(path1, 0.dp, 0.dp, 6.dp)
            .border(3.dp, Color.Green)
    ) {
        drawPath(path1, Color.White)
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(300.dp)
            .vectorShadow(path2, 3.dp, 3.dp, 10.dp)
            .border(3.dp, Color.Green)
    ) {
        drawPath(path2, Color.White)
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

createPolygonPath is a sample function to create Path. If you manage to convert your vector to Path rest is simple.

```
fun createPolygonPath(cx: Float, cy: Float, sides: Int, radius: Float): Path {
    val angle = 2.0 * Math.PI / sides

    return Path().apply {
        moveTo(
            cx + (radius * cos(0.0)).toFloat(),
            cy + (radius * sin(0.0)).toFloat()
        )
        for (i in 1 until sides) {
            lineTo(
                cx + (radius * cos(angle * i)).toFloat(),
                cy + (radius * sin(angle * i)).toFloat()
            )
        }
        close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly what you want but for elevating an icon you can simply do this:

```
Icon(
    Icons.Outlined.Refresh, contentDescription = "back",
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(300.dp)
        .offset(10.dp, 10.dp), tint = Color(0, 0, 0, 40)
)
Icon(
    Icons.Outlined.Refresh, contentDescription = "front",
    modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp), tint = Color(0xFFb6d7a8)
)
```

[image]

The problem is that it is lacking the blurring effect.

Comment: As per the time of this comment, a modifier can be added to the first Icon to add a blur effect:  `Modifier.size(300.dp.offset(10.dp, 10.dp)).blur(radius = 2.dp)`

Answer (score 1):

I have tweaked a little bit answer of @Thracian

I have changed it so that it's no longer modifier, but a composable which draws the VectorImage itself as well as it's shadow

Consider this code:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ShadowedDrawable(
    drawable: ImageVector,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    tint: Color = Color.Black,
    shadowXOffset: Dp = 0.dp,
    shadowYOffset: Dp = 0.dp,
    shadowRadius: Dp = 0.dp
) {

    val vectors = mutableListOf<PathNode>()
    fun recursiveWalkVectors(vectorNode: VectorNode) {
        when (vectorNode) {
            is VectorGroup -> vectorNode.forEach { recursiveWalkVectors(it) }
            is VectorPath -> vectors.addAll(vectorNode.pathData)
        }
    }
    recursiveWalkVectors(drawable.root)
    val path = PathParser().addPathNodes(vectors).toPath()

    val dx: Float
    val dy: Float
    val radiusInPx: Float
    with(LocalDensity.current) {
        dx = shadowXOffset.toPx()
        dy = shadowYOffset.toPx()
        radiusInPx = shadowRadius.toPx()
    }

    val paint = remember {
        Paint().asFrameworkPaint()
    }

    Canvas(modifier = modifier, contentDescription = "drawable with shadow") {
        AdjustPathToCanvas.adjust(path, drawContext.size.toRect())
        drawIntoCanvas {
            paint.color = tint.toArgb()
            paint.setShadowLayer(
                radiusInPx,
                dx,
                dy,
                Color.DarkGray
                    .copy(alpha = 0.9f)
                    .toArgb()
            )
            it.drawPath(path, paint.asComposePaint())
        }

    }
}
```

I will describe what specific code does

```kotlin
    val vectors = mutableListOf<PathNode>()
    fun recursiveWalkVectors(vectorNode: VectorNode) {
        when (vectorNode) {
            is VectorGroup -> vectorNode.forEach { recursiveWalkVectors(it) }
            is VectorPath -> vectors.addAll(vectorNode.pathData)
        }
    }
    recursiveWalkVectors(drawable.root)
    val path = PathParser().addPathNodes(vectors).toPath()
```

Code above is how we convert VectorImage into a Path object. It accesses VectorNodes in ImageVector object and iteratively copies all PathNodes into a simple list

```kotlin
    val dx: Float
    val dy: Float
    val radiusInPx: Float
    with(LocalDensity.current) {
        dx = shadowXOffset.toPx()
        dy = shadowYOffset.toPx()
        radiusInPx = shadowRadius.toPx()
    }
```

Code above simply converts Dp into pixels according to density of the screen

```kotlin
    val paint = remember {
        Paint().asFrameworkPaint()
    }
```

Here we are just declaring Paint object which we will use later to paint on canvas

```kotlin
    Canvas(modifier = modifier, contentDescription = "drawable with shadow") {
        AdjustPathToCanvas.adjust(path, drawContext.size.toRect())
        drawIntoCanvas {
            paint.color = tint.toArgb()
            paint.setShadowLayer(
                radiusInPx,
                dx,
                dy,
                Color.DarkGray
                    .copy(alpha = 0.9f)
                    .toArgb()
            )
            it.drawPath(path, paint.asComposePaint())
        }

    }
```

Here the `AdjustPathToCanvas.adjust(path, drawContext.size.toRect())` part refers to utility function which will adjust size of the VectorImage we paint to available space on canvas. I am new to android so I didn't know how to make it take all available space, albeit I have tried setting Modifier.fillMaxSize and Modifier.size to no avail. The function doesn't exactly answer the question so I will list it at the end

Now the rest of this piece of code more or less translates directly what @Thracian suggested so I will not dive into it.

The idea of this Composable is to replace entirely an Icon or other composables which draw VectorImage which will also handle painting shadow according to shape of the drawable. It is also quiet easy to extend for additional needs as I imagine one would want to use it to replace something more complex than just Icon

Now the adjusting function

```kotlin
        fun adjust(path: Path, availableSpace: Rect) {
            val pathRect = path.getBounds()
            val (translateX, translateY) = availableSpace.left - pathRect.left to availableSpace.top - pathRect.top
            val scale = availableSpace.let {
                minOf<Float>(it.height / pathRect.height, it.width / pathRect.width)
            }
            path.translate(Offset(translateX, translateY))
            path.transform(Matrix().apply { scale(scale, scale) })
        }
```

Here we just translate rectangular within which visible Path object lies. Thanks to this we will have zero offset from top and left sides of canvas.
After figuring out how much we need to translate, we also figure out how bigger canvas is than rectangular which encompasses Path object. I didn't really put much thought to it, so I ended up by just using lesser ratio out of dividing height and width. Somehow it worked but i don't think it might for some cases

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not best solution but I created a Composable function that paints shadow with an offset:

```
@Composable
@NonRestartableComposable
fun ShadowIcon(
    imageVector: ImageVector,
    contentDescription: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    tint: Color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current),
    shadow: AlphaShadow = ShadowIconDefaults.defaultShadow(),
) {
    ShadowIcon(
        painter = rememberVectorPainter(imageVector),
        contentDescription = contentDescription,
        modifier = modifier,
        tint = tint,
        shadow = shadow,
    )
}

@Composable
@NonRestartableComposable
fun ShadowIcon(
    bitmap: ImageBitmap,
    contentDescription: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    tint: Color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current),
    shadow: AlphaShadow = ShadowIconDefaults.defaultShadow(),
) {
    val painter = remember(bitmap) { BitmapPainter(bitmap) }
    ShadowIcon(
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = contentDescription,
        modifier = modifier,
        tint = tint,
        shadow = shadow,
    )
}

@Composable
fun ShadowIcon(
    painter: Painter,
    contentDescription: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    tint: Color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current),
    shadow: AlphaShadow = ShadowIconDefaults.defaultShadow(),
) {
    val colorFilter = if (tint == Color.Unspecified) null else ColorFilter.tint(tint)
    val semantics = if (contentDescription != null) {
        Modifier.semantics {
            this.contentDescription = contentDescription
            this.role = Role.Image
        }
    } else {
        Modifier
    }
    Box(
        modifier
            .toolingGraphicsLayer()
            .defaultSizeFor(painter)
            .offset(shadow.offset.x.dp, shadow.offset.y.dp)
            .paint(
                painter = painter,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(shadow.color),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                alpha = shadow.alpha,
            )
            .offset(-shadow.offset.x.dp, -shadow.offset.y.dp)
            .paint(
                painter = painter,
                colorFilter = colorFilter,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            )
            .then(semantics),
    )
}

object ShadowIconDefaults {
    fun defaultShadow(
        color: Color = Color(0xFF000000),
        offset: Offset = Offset(1f, 1f),
        alpha: Float = 0.1f
    ) = AlphaShadow(color, offset, alpha)

}

private fun Modifier.defaultSizeFor(painter: Painter) =
    this.then(
        if (painter.intrinsicSize == Size.Unspecified || painter.intrinsicSize.isInfinite()) {
            DefaultIconSizeModifier
        } else {
            Modifier
        },
    )

private fun Size.isInfinite() = width.isInfinite() && height.isInfinite()

// Default icon size, for icons with no intrinsic size information
@Suppress("PrivatePropertyName")
private val DefaultIconSizeModifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
```

And the AlphaShadow class:

```
/**
 * Copy of [Shadow] but replaced blur with alpha.
 */
@Immutable
class AlphaShadow(
    @Stable
    val color: Color = Color(0xFF000000),
    @Stable
    val offset: Offset = Offset.Zero,
    @Stable
    val alpha: Float = 0.0f
) {
    companion object {
        /**
         * Constant for no shadow.
         */
        @Stable
        val None = AlphaShadow()
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other !is AlphaShadow) return false

        if (color != other.color) return false
        if (offset != other.offset) return false
        if (alpha != other.alpha) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = color.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + offset.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + alpha.hashCode()
        return result
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "AlphaShadow(color=$color, offset=$offset, alpha=$alpha)"
    }

    fun copy(
        color: Color = this.color,
        offset: Offset = this.offset,
        alpha: Float = this.alpha
    ): AlphaShadow {
        return AlphaShadow(
            color = color,
            offset = offset,
            alpha = alpha
        )
    }
}

/**
 * Linearly interpolate two [AlphaShadow]s.
 */
@Stable
fun lerp(start: AlphaShadow, stop: AlphaShadow, fraction: Float): AlphaShadow {
    return AlphaShadow(
        lerp(start.color, stop.color, fraction),
        lerp(start.offset, stop.offset, fraction),
        lerp(start.alpha, stop.alpha, fraction)
    )
}
```