# Jetpack Compose ImageVector to Path/Shape

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to get an Icon shadow in Jetpack Compose and already opened a question for that: [Jetpack Compose icon shadow/elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72941049/jetpack-compose-icon-shadow-elevation/72942226#72942226)

The proposed solution requires to convert an `ImageVector` or XML resource to `Path` or `Shape`, but I don't seem to find a solution for that.

Has anyone ever stumbled upon a library or other solution to that problem?

Comment: https://github.com/DevSrSouza/svg-to-compose

Comment: @Thracian i might be wrong but I haven't seen a way to convert to path or shape

Comment: I will look into it and check few others when i'm available. You can search vectorDrawble to path for jetpack compose. I initially found this one which looks like returning path but it says to check one i initially posted. https://github.com/mohsenoid/SvgToCompose